# My recursive function in python keeps returning none in python

Tags: python, recursion, nonetype

```
def recursiveSearch(rootDir):
    file = 'foundMe'

    # Creates a full path back to the root directory with each item in list
    for p in os.listdir(rootDir):
        path = os.path.join(rootDir, p)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
                if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] == file:
                    print("congrats you found", path)

                    return path

        else:
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                recursiveSearch(path)

x = recursiveSearch(rootDir)
print(x) ->>> None
```

Why does this function return the None type and not the path of the file that I have found?

When I run the function, the recursion works and is able to find and print the path to the file, but nothing is returned. Could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not explicitly `return`ing the value of the recursive call, so *implicitly* the function returns `None` in the `else` branch. Instead, use:

```
...

else:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return recursiveSearch(path)
```

Comment: @Matt Feel free to declare this the correct answer ;)

Comment: Ah. gotcha - so *merci*. A simple problem but probably common enough for beginners.